# PHPSECLIB: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Connection closed by server'

Tags: php, phpseclib

This is my first time posting a question here, so bear with me.  I am at my wits end with this problem.  Have described the problem in great detail below.  What I am looking for are potential causes and possible remedies for the following error occurring after running a phpseclib script...

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Connection closed by server' in /home/electroline_admin/orders.electrolineelectronics.com/classes/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:1075

Stack trace:

> /home/electroline_admin/orders.electrolineelectronics.com/classes/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php(1877):
>   phpseclib\Net\SSH2->_connect() [internal function]:
>   phpseclib\Net\SSH2->_login('electroline', 'Bitter8Steal_Wr...')
>
> /home/electroline_admin/orders.electrolineelectronics.com/classes/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php(394):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> /home/electroline_admin/orders.electrolineelectronics.com/classes/class.orders.php(4974):
>   phpseclib\Net\SFTP->login('electroline', 'Bitter8Steal_Wr...')
>
> /home/electroline_admin/orders.electrolineelectronics.com/live_orders_test.php(31):
>   orders->ftp_in_nd(Array, '1383317685.md5E...', '/home/electroli...')
>
> {main}   thrown in
>   /home/electroline_admin/orders.electrolineelectronics.com/classes/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
>   on line 1075 electroline_admin@ps80038:~$ /usr/local/php54/bin/php
>   /home/electroline_admin/orders.electrolineelectronics.com/live_orders_test.php

Did all of the diligent research regarding similar issues, but nothing seems to point toward a meaningful answer.  My initial suspicion was that there is a timeout issue, since this script is calling and pulling batches of files at various numbers small and large.  So I increased the timeout limit, but that failed to solve the issue.

Any insights would be deeply appreciated.  Thanks!!!

A detailed code overview is provided below....

The code that caused the error is as follows...

```
public function pending_ftp()
{
    $dumped_arr = array('MAM');
    $cust_query = "SELECT DISTINCT `ID` AS ID,`CHUB` AS CH FROM `$this->tbl_cu`";
    $res_cust = $this->query($cust_query);

    if($res_cust[1])
    {
        while($cust_arr = mysql_fetch_array($res_cust[0],MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $cust = $cust_arr['ID'];
            $chub = $cust_arr['CH'];
            if($chub == 'Y') $stg = $this->chub_ftp_settings($cust);
            elseif($cust == 'QBD') $stg = array('URL' => 'edi.esadmin.com','USR' => 'Electroline','PSW' => 'tVd&hP4','PRT' => 21,'DIR' => '/to_Electroline');
            else $stg = false;

            $pend_dir = '/home/electroline_admin/orders.electrolineelectronics.com/pending/'.strtolower($cust);

            if($stg)
            {
                $new_files = $this->ftp_get_filelist($stg); // METHOD CALLING PHPSECLIB CALLABLE

                foreach($new_files as $inx => $file_path)
                {
                    $file_info = pathinfo($file_path);
                    $file = $file_info['basename'];
                    $pend_path = $pend_dir.'/'.$file;
                    $ftp_sts = $this->ftp_in_nd($stg,$file,$pend_path); // METHOD CALLING PHPSECLIB CALLABLE
                }
            }
            elseif(in_array($cust,$dumped_arr))
            {
                $dump_dir = '/home/electroline_admin/orders.electrolineelectronics.com/dump/'.strtolower($cust);
                $dump_files = scandir($dump_dir);
                $not_a_file = array('.','..');

                foreach($dump_files as $inx => $file)
                {
                    if(!in_array($file,$not_a_file))
                    {
                        $dump_path = $dump_dir.'/'.$file;
                        $pend_path = $pend_dir.'/'.$file;

                        if(file_exists($dump_path)) $dump_copy = copy($dump_path,$pend_path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and the specific method encasing the phpseclib callable is as follows

```
public function ftp_in_nd($settings,$remote_file,$local_path)
{
    if(isset($settings))
    {
        $furl = $settings['URL'];
        $fusr = $settings['USR'];
        $fpwd = $settings['PSW'];
        $fprt = is_numeric($settings['PRT']) && $settings['PRT'] > 0 ?  $settings['PRT'] : 21;
        $fdir = strlen($settings['DIR']) > 0 ? $settings['DIR'] : ''; 

        if($fprt == 22)
        {
            $fcon = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP($furl,$fprt,30); // PHPSECLIB

            if($fcon->login($fusr,$fpwd)) // PHPSECLIB
            {
                $fmsg = "SFTP LOGIN SUCCESS ($fusr): $furl".(is_numeric($fprt) ? " on port $fprt" : '')." on ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                $fmsg .= "FILE DOWNLOAD ATTEMPT ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";

                $fcon->chdir($fdir);

                if($fcon->get($remote_file,$local_path)) // PHPSECLIB
                {
                    $fmsg .= "FILE DOWNLOADED ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";

                    if(file_exists($local_path))
                    {
                        $fmsg .= "DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFULLY VERIFIED ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                        $fstat = "SUCCESS";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $fmsg .= "DOWNLOAD NOT VERIFIED ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                        $fstat = "UNVERIFIED";
                    }

                    goto bottom;
                }
                else
                {
                    $fmsg .= "FILE DOWNLOAD FAIL ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                    $fstat = "FAIL";    
                    goto bottom;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $fmsg .= "SFTP LOGIN FAIL ($fusr): file transfer attempt aborted on ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                $fstat = "FAIL";
                goto bottom;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($fcon = ftp_connect($furl,(is_numeric($fprt) ? $fprt : 21)))
            {
                $fmsg = "FTP CONNECT SUCCESS: $furl".(is_numeric($fprt) ? " on port $fprt" : '')." on ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";

                if(ftp_login($fcon,$fusr,$fpwd))
                {
                    $fmsg .= "FTP LOGIN SUCCESS ($fusr): $furl".(is_numeric($fprt) ? " on port $fprt" : 21)." on ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                    $fmsg .= "FILE DOWNLOAD ATTEMPT ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";

                    ftp_chdir($fcon,$fdir);

                    if(ftp_get($fcon,$local_path,$remote_file,FTP_BINARY))
                    {
                        $fmsg .= "FILE DOWNLOADED ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";

                        if(file_exists($local_path))
                        {
                            $fmsg .= "DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFULLY VERIFIED ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                            $fstat = "SUCCESS";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $fmsg .= "FILE DOWNLOAD NOT VERIFIED ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                            $fstat = "UNVERIFIED";  
                        }

                        goto bottom;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $fmsg .= "FILE DOWNLOAD FAIL ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                        $fstat = "FAIL";
                        goto bottom;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $fmsg .= "FTP LOGIN FAIL ($fusr): file transfer attempt aborted on ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                    $fstat = "FAIL";
                    goto bottom;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $fmsg = "FTP CONNECT FAIL: file transfer attempt aborted on ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
                $fstat = "FAIL";
                goto bottom;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $fmsg = "FTP SETTINGS NOT PROVIDED: file transfer attempt aborted on ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."\r\n";
        $fstat = "FAIL";
        goto bottom;
    }

    bottom:

    if(!isset($fmsg)) $fmsg = "FTP NOT PROCESSED: process abandoned on ".date('Y-m-d @ H:i:s',time())."; check settings and reprocess\r\n";
    if(!isset($fstat)) $fstat = "FAIL";

    $stat['SID'] = $fstat;
    $stat['MSG'] = $fmsg;

    return $stat;
}
```

From my own actions and intelligence gathering, it appears that a failed connection is happening when this method is called from the phpseclib SSH2 class...

```
function _connect()
{
    if ($this->bitmap & self::MASK_CONSTRUCTOR) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->bitmap |= self::MASK_CONSTRUCTOR;

    $this->curTimeout = $this->timeout;

    $this->last_packet = microtime(true);

    if (!is_resource($this->fsock)) {
        $start = microtime(true);
        $this->fsock = @fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->curTimeout);
        if (!$this->fsock) {
            $host = $this->host . ':' . $this->port;
            throw new \RuntimeException(rtrim("Cannot connect to $host. Error $errno. $errstr"));
        }
        $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;

        $this->curTimeout-= $elapsed;

        if ($this->curTimeout <= 0) {
            $this->is_timeout = true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* According to the SSH2 specs,

      "The server MAY send other lines of data before sending the version
       string.  Each line SHOULD be terminated by a Carriage Return and Line
       Feed.  Such lines MUST NOT begin with "SSH-", and SHOULD be encoded
       in ISO-10646 UTF-8 [RFC3629] (language is not specified).  Clients
       MUST be able to process such lines." */
    $temp = '';
    $extra = '';
    while (!feof($this->fsock) && !preg_match('#^SSH-(\d\.\d+)#', $temp, $matches)) {
        if (substr($temp, -2) == "\r\n") {
            $extra.= $temp;
            $temp = '';
        }

        if ($this->curTimeout) {
            if ($this->curTimeout < 0) {
                $this->is_timeout = true;
                return false;
            }
            $read = array($this->fsock);
            $write = $except = null;
            $start = microtime(true);
            $sec = floor($this->curTimeout);
            $usec = 1000000 * ($this->curTimeout - $sec);
            // on windows this returns a "Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected" error
            // the !count() is done as a workaround for <https://bugs.php.net/42682>
            if (!@stream_select($read, $write, $except, $sec, $usec) && !count($read)) {
                $this->is_timeout = true;
                return false;
            }
            $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
            $this->curTimeout-= $elapsed;
        }

        $temp.= fgets($this->fsock, 255);
    }

    **if (feof($this->fsock)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Connection closed by server');
    }  // SCRIPT FAILS HERE!!! **

    $this->identifier = $this->_generate_identifier();

    if (defined('NET_SSH2_LOGGING')) {
        $this->_append_log('<-', $extra . $temp);
        $this->_append_log('->', $this->identifier . "\r\n");
    }

    $this->server_identifier = trim($temp, "\r\n");
    if (strlen($extra)) {
        $this->errors[] = utf8_decode($extra);
    }

    if ($matches[1] != '1.99' && $matches[1] != '2.0') {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Cannot connect to SSH $matches[1] servers");
    }

    fputs($this->fsock, $this->identifier . "\r\n");

    $response = $this->_get_binary_packet();
    if ($response === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Connection closed by server');
    }

    if (ord($response[0]) != NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT) {
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Expected SSH_MSG_KEXINIT');
    }

    if (!$this->_key_exchange($response)) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->bitmap|= self::MASK_CONNECTED;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm able to connect just fine:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('orders.electrolineelectronics.com');
$ssh->login('zzz', 'zzz');

echo $ssh->getLog();
```

I mean, I'm not able to successfully authenticate but I'm able make the authentication attempt.

In light of this my guess is that the problem is with the computer that's attempting to make the connection. Something with the environment. Maybe you have selinux installed, which by default, prevents fsockopen from working correctly:

http://yml.com/fv-b-1-619/selinux--apache-httpd--php-establishing-socket-connections-using-fsockopen---et-al.html

Or maybe your hosts has `orders.electrolineelectronics.com` pointing to some other IP address that doesn't have an SSH server installed or something.

Could be any number of issues but the fact that I'm able to connect with phpseclib just fine makes me think the problem is environmental. Especially since it's dying before it's actually managed to send any data (assuming your analysis is correct).